# Why is SVC().decision_function() so slow?

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to use `sklearn.svm.SVC` on a large dataset (without much success), and I came upon an interesting phenomena: somewhy, `SVC().decision_function()` is *significantly* slower than SVC().predict (~**20** times slower). The same holds for `SVC().fit` and for kernel computation (both `XX` and `YY`), both of which are even faster than `SVC().predict()`.

I'm using a precomputed kernel with C=100, I have 5-10k classes and the same number of queries. I was expecting (since predict is probably supposed to use `decision_function` inside, but I'm not so sure anymore) predict to be a bit slower. Due to absurd memory requirements, I was also forced to split the queries into chunks, processing them one chunk at a time.

Kernel computation (both `XX` and `XY`) and model fitting took no time at all when compared to calculating the decision function (seconds vs *hours*). This really bugged me out, since I expected the pairwise distance calculation to be the most computationally expensive step of the algorithm, and training not far after.

I tried distributing the prediction across multiple cores (by splitting the test data into chunks, and distributing decision function computation for each chunk across cores), I couldn't get enough CPU load (even for 2 threads it was well below 100%), due to SVM's huge appetite for RAM: in multithreading I'm forced to split probes into even smaller pieces for the whole thing to fit. Note, that fit, while being single-threaded in vanilla sklearn (I checked on `htop`) is way faster.

I need the decision function to get pairwise scores for my metric. I'm already considering doing it manually, but it seems silly for me to hope that my python implementation will overcome libsvm. Does anyone have tips on how to speed it up, or an explanation why all I'm seeing is to be expected? Any help appreciated!

**TL;DR** What is the complexity for SVM decision function on a precomputed kernel (ignoring pairwise distance computation)? Is decision function computation *really* supposed to be slower than everything else, or is it just sklearn?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community thanks, added a TL;DR, is that better?

Answer (score 1):

The speed difference between `SVC().predict()` and `SVC().decision_function()` comes from what they are computing:

- `SVC().predict()`: outputs only the final predicted classes for your data, it doesn't need to output all the decision function values for every class
- `SVC().decision_function()`: is computing the distances to the separating hyperplane for each class, which is more computationally expensive (particularly in a multi-class problem)

So, the reason `SVC().predict()` seems faster is not that it's computing the same thing as `SVC().decision_function()` more quickly, but rather it's computing less.

For speeding up the `SVC().decision_function()`, the best way to do this would likely be to reduce the complexity of your model, either by reducing the number of classes (if possible) or reducing the dimensionality of your data. Dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA might be helpful. Alternatively, you could try using more powerful hardware or distributing your computation across multiple cores or machines, if possible.
Another options is using Random Forest which, remember that the complexity for SVC is **O(n * f^2)** (where 'n' is the number of samples and 'f' is the number of features, [1](https://alekhyo.medium.com/computational-complexity-of-svm-4d3cacf2f952)), and for Random it is **O(t nlog(n))** (where 't' is the number of trees in the forest, 'n' is the number of samples, [2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-time-complexity-of-a-Random-Forest-both-building-the-model-and-classification)).

[SVC complexity order](https://alekhyo.medium.com/computational-complexity-of-svm-4d3cacf2f952)
[Random Forest complexity order](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-time-complexity-of-a-Random-Forest-both-building-the-model-and-classification)

Comment: Also, O(nf^2) is training complexity, my question is on the prediction complexity. In my case, training occupies a fraction of running time, which doesn't match the data in the link